# Export collection of plots to A4 pdf

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

Sometimes I want to Export a collection of plots or other Graphics to a pdf in A4 format. Right now I'm using a GraphicsGrid inside a panel which is an inset in a Graphics object. Here is an example:

```
    Module[{plot},
   plot := ListPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10], ImageSize -> 400];
   Graphics[{Inset[
      Panel[GraphicsGrid[{{plot, plot}, {plot, plot}, {plot, 
          plot}}], {Style["Title\n", Directive[20, Bold]]}, {Top}, 
       Background -> White], ImageScaled[{0.52, 0.5}]]}, 
    ImageSize -> {210*5, 297*5}]
   ] // Set[visu, #] &;

visu // Print;
```

This solution looks rather convoluted to me. Is there a better way to create a pdf containing these plots?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an overall page title and a different label on each subfigure:

```
Column[
 {Text[Style["Here are all my graphs", 24, Bold, Blue]],
  Grid[
   Partition[
    Table[
     ListPlot[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10], ImageSize -> 400,  
      PlotLabel -> "Figure number " <> ToString[i]], {i, 9}], 3]]},
 Alignment -> Center]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would like to have the possibility, to place the plots on the sheet, to add a title, a legend, ... . I think Grid doesn't give me enough flexibility

Comment: A title for the full set, or a title on each subgraph?  Both are trivial.

Comment: thanks, but now after adding the title the format of the pdf changes. That's why I chose to use Graphics with a fixed image size together with Inset.